# Using jquery datatable in MVC4 webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I am using WebGrid in my MVC4 application. Now I want to use the **jquery datatable** with this webgrid to give it extra functionality of filter. I have made the webgrid to datatable using below code.

$('#wbGrid').dataTable();

My problem is the pagination of this datatable is not working if I keep the pagination of webgrid. I can remove the pagination of webgrid but then it take too much time to load when there is huge amount of data(around 30000 rows).

Is there a way to connect the datatable pagination to webgrid pagination ? I need the pagination to be updated as I use the datatable filter.

Comment: Can you not just use the datatable _instead_ of webgrid?  It seems like they offer similar functionality(i'm not familiar with webgrid tbh).

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code in java script to enable sorting paging filtering in grid

```
enter code herevar oTable = $('#infotable').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "sDom": '<"H"ilfr>t<"F"p>',
    "fnInfoCallback": function (oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre) { return "Showing " + iTotal + " entries"; },
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
        $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex + 1);
        return nRow;
    }
```